# Como fazer cache de arquivos com assinatura (Service worker)

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Diversas aplicações front-end implementam um modelo de assinatura nos arquivos para controlar o cache, e cada alteração no arquivo essa assinatura muda.

Exemplos de assinatura:

sw-d58e3582afa99040e27b92b13c8f2280.js
sw.js?_gc=20180101

Como fazer com que o Service Worker saiba lidar com essas assinaturas e faça o cache?

+detalhes
Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação já pronta, tentando implementar service worker para determinadas funcionalidades ficarem disponiveis offline.

Exemplo, neste trecho preciso dizer o que farei cache, no entanto, a aplicação muda as assinaturas do arquivo para controlar o cache. (hoje está assim)

```
caches.open('my-cache').then(function(cache) {
return cache.addAll([
    '/index.html',
    '/styles.css',
    '/main.js'
]);})
```

A aplicacao esté sempre alterando "styles.css" para "styles.css?v=1527624807103_1" (timestamp)
Até onde entendi, não "styles.css" não é a mesma coisa que "styles.css?v=1527624807103_1".

Comment: por favor poderia explicar um pouco melhor e se possível colocar um exemplo?

Comment: @AlexandreCavaloti tentei colocar mais informações no primeiro texto. Espero ter esclarecido um pouco mais...